# USB-C -> HDMI connected Monitor freezes randomly

Tags: nvidia, usb, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have a laptop (MSI Cyborg 15 A13V with Nvidia Geforce RTX 4050, Ubuntu 22.04) that has an HDMI and USB-C port. I have a monitor attached to the HDMI and USB-C port (USB-C to HDMI converter). The monitor on the USB-C Connection works fine for a few minutes, **but then the image becomes frozen**. The other monitors (Built-in and HDMI) respond fine. I have tried this on both X-Org, Wayland, and Unity, and got the same result.

On my Windows partition, both the HDMI and USB-C work fine, with no freezing issues. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include the version of the Ubuntu OS that you're running? Also add the make/model of the laptop that your using, as other users of this hardware may run into similar problems in the future. Thanks

Comment: @richbl I added the specs